# PowerShell giving an error "Object reference not set to an instance object"

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

Am receiving an error from my powershell script everytime it runs. However, it does run successfully. I would like to know what is causing the error message. Thanks!

PowerShell:

```
 [xml]$file = get-content "c:\Windows\personalsettings\PersonalSettings.xml"
  $xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("/Objects/Object/Property")
   If ($xmlProperties.Where({ $_.InnerText -eq 'FireFox' }, 'First'))
    {
    Invoke-expression "C:\Windows\SetDefaultBrowser\setdefaultbrowser"
  }
   If ($xmlProperties.Where({ $_.InnerText -eq 'Chrome' }, 'First'))
  { 
  Invoke-expression "C:\Windows\psu\protected\SetDefaultBrowser\setdefaultbrowser"
 }
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
<Object>
<Property Name="Browser">Firefox</Property>
<Property Name="PDF">Adobe Reader</Property>
</Object>
</Objects>
```

Comment: so ... what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you can see the error in the title.

Comment: I suspect your error is in one of the files you invoke (this part works fine).

Comment: Please share the _full error message_

Comment: you need to post the FULL TEXT of the _entire error message_. plus, all the info about the problem needs to be IN THE POST, not scattered in bits and parts here and there and everywhere.

Comment: Please create an [mcve] by removing the invokes or adding the concerned content to the question. Also consider to add the xml contents in a string to the example (e.g.: `[xml]$file = '<?xml version="1.0"?> ...`) to easily reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

The xml file is declared with a namespace `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and that's why it is not selecting the nodes. It will be better to get the values like ordinary objects:

```
$file = [xml](Get-Content "c:\Windows\personalsettings\PersonalSettings.xml")
$file.objects.object.property | ForEach {
  If ($_.Innertext -eq "Firefox") {
    Invoke-expression "C:\Windows\SetDefaultBrowser\setdefaultbrowser"
  }
  If ($_.Innertext -eq "Chrome") {
    Invoke-expression "C:\Windows\psu\protected\SetDefaultBrowser\setdefaultbrowser"
  }
}
```

Comment: The nodes are selected just fine (even with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`)

Comment: @iRon are you sure? I posted a similar looking answer problems with node selection. As it didn't declared namespace it didn't work. But after adding the namespace it worked. Even method like this worked. Invoke-Expression ... can still be a problem because which file is invoked does not have any extension, so this can be even a problem. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: It works better now. Thanks Guys. Just an additional question. How would you update the attribute for "<Property Name="Browser">Firefox</Property>".